# Problem with php-cs-fixer after upgrade php to version 8

Tags: php, php-8, php-cs-fixer

After upgrade to php8 I have a problem with `php-cs-fixer` which I installed globally via composer. Right now I can not use `php-cs-fixer` because every time I get:

```
PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.6.0 and maximum version of PHP 7.4.*.
To ignore this requirement please set `PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV`.
```

For php upgrade and usage different version of php I use https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

For previous version of php (7.4) everything works fine.

Comment: PHP 8 has been out for less than two months; it's going to take a while for all the tools you use to be ready for it!

Comment: I got a similar issue today because current version of cs fixer (3.14.4) does not support php above 8.1 (for a good reason actually https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/6787 ) but using PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV works (I guess it would fail if you use it on a file with specific 8.2 syntax)

Answer (score 8):

The first version of php-cs-fixer to support PHP 8 was [Version 2.18](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/tag/v2.18.0) released on 18th Jan 2021.

Answer (score 6):

https://cs.symfony.com/doc/usage.html#environment-options

`PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV=1 php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 0):

The PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV environment variable can be used to ignore any environment requirements. This includes requirements like missing PHP extensions, unsupported PHP versions or by using HHVM.

NOTE: Execution may be unstable when used.

```
PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV=1 php php-cs-fixer.phar fix /path/to/dir
```

Exit code of the fix command is built using following bit flags:

0 - OK.

1 - General error (or PHP minimal requirement not matched).

4 - Some files have invalid syntax (only in dry-run mode).

8 - Some files need fixing (only in dry-run mode).

16 - Configuration error of the application.

32 - Configuration error of a Fixer.

64 - Exception raised within the application.

Answer (score -3):

In the file: `./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer`

Remove the code below (starting at line 26):

```
elseif (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID') || \PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600 || \PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70500) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.6.0 and maximum version of PHP 7.4.*.\n");

    if (getenv('PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV')) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "Ignoring environment requirements because `PHP_CS_FIXER_IGNORE_ENV` is set. Execution may be unstable.\n");
    } else {
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

It's a quick fix, but it will get you back up and running.

Comment: Ok but I would like to set this environment. Version 2.18 solve my problems